# Area 51 - discussion not showing up under proposal

Tags: support, area-51

I'm trying out the new discussion feature at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). I added a new [discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/please-can-all-followers-and-visitors-vote-on-the-questions-here) on my [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia) but I can't find it under the proposal. Why is that?

Comment: My original theory was that it was because the discussion was closed, but [Skeptic Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptic-exchange) proves this otherwise. Perhaps it is because the "Proposals" element was removed from the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposal must be linked to from the question or answer body.  It works the same way as [Linked Posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/), i.e. it searches the question body for links and adds relations when it finds them.

Comment: so, the questions are **Area 51 wide** then and *not* linked to a specific proposal? I originally understood that each proposal had its own Q&A area - that is not the case?

Comment: @Wikis That's correct -- discuss.area51.stackexchange.com is a general-purpose Q&A site for discussing Area 51 proposals and the proposal process.  Questions can be linked to proposals, but they don't have to be.

Comment: OK, thanks. Now I'm beginning to understand part of the reason behind my other question... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76947/please-can-you-clarify-what-may-may-not-be-discussed-now-on-area-51