# Please can you clarify what may / may not be discussed now on Area 51

Tags: discussion, area-51

I started [a discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/please-can-all-followers-and-visitors-vote-on-the-questions-here) under [my proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia) asking people (especially followers) to vote to get the proposal to the next stage (commitment).

The question (discussion) was closed. I'm puzzled by this because I did this because I saw an identical request as a *comment* on a previous commitment at Area 51 *(will link as soon as I find it)*.

So - what are the rules here? E.g. why can't someone **on the proposal itself** ask followers to vote on the site? It's not as if I'm publishing the question to all of Area 51 - only to followers / visitors of that site *(correct me if I'm wrong)*.

Comment: Part of the answer (the most important to me) has already been supplied by David here (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/area-51-discussion-not-showing-up-under-proposal/76950#76950). The Area 51 discussion are all **site wide** - I thought they were only displayed on the proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I see that you resolved the issue, but just to document an answer…*

The Area 51 "Discussion Zone" is intended to discuss the issues of getting proposals properly defined and launched. While I'm sure everyone would like to see their proposals followed and their questions voted, we simply cannot allow a glut of "Vote for me!" posts to spam up the site. It is simply outside the scope and purpose of that site.

*But I can see how it might appear that you were posting a proposal-specific discussion. No worries. The site has just barely started and we are all all learning our way through this process.*

Comment: yes, that's right. It was a simple misunderstanding of the intention of the site. Thanks for the gracious response.